# How can I manually install gcc tarball file in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, gcc

How can I manually install gcc tarball file in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages from source with `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get -y build-dep gcc
apt-get source gcc
cd gcc*
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i gcc*.deb
```